# ffmpeg - How to resize frame collage (grid of images) to grid of different dimensions, while respecting frame order?

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I have an input of a "frame collage" (that is, frames extracted from a video, arranged in a certain grid). I want to rearrange the frames from a collage into a different grid shape. I can calculate the input coordinates (or bounds, e.g. x.min -> x.max, y.min -> y.max) and output coordinates for each frame. Basically, I want to resize a grid, while respecting the positioning of each element of the original grid.

As an example, given a frame collage that is 9x2 (9 columns wide, 2 rows tall), with image resolution of 1080x240 (width x height), resize the frame collage to be 6x3 (6 columns wide, 3 columns tall), with an image resolution of 720x480 (width x height), while respecting the order of the frames in the input image (left to right, top to bottom).

I generated the frame mappings (where the original frame was located, and where the new frame should be placed) for each frame, a table of that data is available here: https://pastebin.com/raw/a5UhKhek (posted on pastebin because discord would murder the formatting).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to pull this off?

I've investigated the `tile` and `untile` filter, as well as looked into the `select` filter, although the syntax for the lattermost is a touch confusing to me.

Comment: build a "complex" filter (different from simple filters). make a stream for each tile by cropping from the source video multiple times. then compose them as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that uses a temporary directory to store the extracted frames.

Extract the frames:
`ffmpeg -i collage.jpg -y -filter:v untile=<input_columns>x<input_rows> collage_frames\frame-%03d.bmp`

Recombine the frames:
`ffmpeg -i collage_frames\frame-%03d.bmp -y -filter:v tile=<output_columns>x<output_rows> resized.jpg`

If anyone can come up with a solution that doesn't require the usage of a temporary directory... I'm all ears! :)